# Issue with link library when compiling with cmake

Tags: cmake, g++, gmp, mpfr, catkin

I can compile a cpp file with g++ using the command:

```
g++ test.cpp -lmpfr -lgmp
```

How to add these libraries to a CMakeLists.txt to compile with CMake?

Comment: Is `target_link_libraries(test mpfr gmp)` insufficient?

Answer (score 0):

It would recommend you to go through [CMake tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/), "Adding a Library (Step 2)" and [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) documentation.